# PostgreSQL error when trying to create an extension

Tags: database, postgresql

`ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory`

Is what I get when I try to `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` can anybody tell me why is it so and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Did you download (and build) the PostGIS extension? It is not included by default in a Postgres installation.

Comment: I installed it using `apt-get install postgis`

Comment: Hey Xeen, what is your final solutions.. please update i have same issue...do all below things but not solve still.

Answer (score 26):

The following will get you a working postgis install on Ubuntu 12.04 (Note: also tested on 13.10)

```
echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/postgis.list
wget --quiet -O - http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3 postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 postgresql-client-9.3
sudo -u postgres psql -c 'create extension postgis;'
```

Based on the docs at https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt

Comment: postgres 9.1 is still installed, try removing it

Comment: Does neither work with 9.1 nor 9.3 when doing sudo -u postgres psql -c 'create extension postgis;'
: FEHLER:  konnte nicht auf Datei »$libdir/postgis-2.1« zugreifen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

Comment: Thanks buddy i solve same issue after remove 9.1 and install 9.3

Comment: What about for Windows?

Comment: @imray I suggest you [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for help on Windows. Don't forget to search first :)

Answer (score 26):

You need to install `postgresql-9.1-postgis-scripts`. In Ubuntu or Debian, you need to run the following command as root:

```
apt-get install postgresql-9.1-postgis-scripts
```

This adds the files needed to create the `postgis` extensions.

Comment: I already had this installed, but I can't find the specific control files that my postgres is complaining about. Maybe the database I'm importing is coming from a different version of postgis or something.

Comment: This still works on Ubuntu, substituting `postgresql-9.3-postgis-scripts` for the package.

Comment: `apt-get install postgresql-XYZ-postgis-scripts` worked for me, where `XYZ` is the major version of PostgreSQL

Comment: This resolved the issue for me on Ubuntu 20.04!

Answer (score 11):

Installing this package did the trick for me on my Linux Mint 16 box:

```
# install hstore postgresql extension.
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib
```

Comment: I already had this installed, so it's not necessarily the right answer. Still, good to have it posted. +1

Comment: +1 for this answer as well. It's way to enable extensions. Found solution [here](http://learn.linksprite.com/pcduino/linux-applications/postgresql-error-could-not-open-extension-control-file-usrsharepostgresql9-3extensiontablefunc-control-no-such-file-or-directory/).

Comment: Linux Mint 18 Sarah - installing postgres-contrib-9.4 did the trick

Comment: This fixed it for me on a Debian 7 (Wheezy) installation, did not need "postgresql-9.1-postgis" at all.

Answer (score 5):

Daniel Vérité is close to the truth, but not enough. The package missing is `postgresql-9.1-postgis-2.0`:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1-postgis-2.0
```

Comment: Not sure which version of Ubuntu you're using. For me on 12.04, Daniel's answer worked but I couldn't find the package you listed.

Comment: I used `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1-postgis-2.1`.

Answer (score 4):

Presumably the `postgis` version you installed is 1.5.x which doesn't come as an extension, but as a couple of SQL scripts that need to be manually applied to create the necessary SQL objects.

Also the `postgis` package is not enough, it contains only stuff that doesn't depend on PG version, you need `postgresql-9.1-postgis` (`dpkg -L package-name` is handy to check out the files provided by any particular package).

Once the installation paths are known, the official [install documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/ch02.html#id354505) should be good enough to set up the template database.

Answer (score 4):

Just resolved it.
You have to uninstall postgis-1.5. You installed it instaed of PostGIS 2.0. As soon as you will install `postgis-2.0` you will see corrected libraries in extension directory.
Before installing you should to add a correct repository (see http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/doc/src/installation/index.html#ubuntu-debian). Use `ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable` for PostGIS 2.0.
Try one of

```bsh
apt-get remove postgis
apt-get remove postgresql-9.1-postgis
apt-get install postgresql-9.1-postgis
```

I couldn't remove and install because of dependencies error.
After a few attmpts, I just removed `postgresql-9.1-postgis` and apt-get offer me upgrade it to 2.0.

Comment: apt-get install postgresql-9.1-postgis-2.0

Answer (score 4):

In C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4 I found uninstall-postgis-bundle-pg94x64-2.1.5-2.exe. Running that fixed my problem, which was caused by a reinstall of PostgreSQL without first uninstalling, and without installing PostGIS the second time around. That's what happens when you more than one person installing stuff..

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on my Window 8.1 setup.

I solved it by simply using `Application StackBuilder` which comes with Postgres and installing PostGIS again (despite not having uninstalled it)

Works fine now!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have installed this

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3-postgis
```

I was facing same issue due to missing this package.

Answer (score 2):

On 14.04, there is [`postgresql-9.3-postgis-scripts`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/postgresql-9.3-postgis-scripts), which [contains](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/postgresql-9.3-postgis-scripts/filelist) the `postgis.control` file.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
apt-get install postgis
```

Answer (score 0):

CentOS needs a different package for this problem. For CentOS 6, if you're using the PGDG yum repository at http://yum.pgdgrpms.org/9.3/redhat/, install the postgresql93-contrib package with the command 'yum install postgresql93-contrib.

Update and edit as necessary for PostgreSQL 9.4.

Answer (score 0):

I had my worst nightmare while installing Postgis 2.X on SLES 12 SP1. which doesnt have compatible package in zypper repo

Here is how is resolved it on my Postgres server instance running 9.4.X

**Prerequsite packages which i have installed prior to PostGis based on the errors**

```
Proj 4 Download source cold, Build --> make install
install Gdal andjibson by adding zypper repo zypper addrepo http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Application:Geo/SLE_12_SP1_Backports/Application:Geo.repo
zypper install gdal gdal-devel libjson-c-devel libjson
```

**Installing Postgis**

```
Download postgis source code (http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/source/postgis-2.3.0rc1.tar.gz)

Go to Postgis folder 
./configure --with-pgconfig=/usr/lib/postgresql94/bin/pg_config --with-geosconfig=/usr/local/bin/geos-config 
make 
make install
```

now if you goto postgress DB and create extension postgis; it will work

**Important** while configuring you should specify pg-config path and geosconfig path and You SHOULD NOT include "without Raster" as RASTER plays main role in creating the postgis extension

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

```
   SELECT PostGIS_full_version();
```

To create postgisis run above query in query panel

And for remove postgis from your database run bellow query

```
   drop extension postgis
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows system download the `postgis.bundle.exe` and manually install in `C:/(PostgreSQLdirectory/version/ )` and that's all .

Comment: Can you expand and explain? OP asked **why**.

Comment: when you are execute `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` query, it will search the reference file from `"directory/postgresql/version/extension/postgis.control"` location and it's not available,  so you can manually install postgis bundle and later you can execute the  `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`query  . 
P.S. you need to checked postgis option in between installation process